# How to get the records in last 24 hrs when the query is run at 00:05 hrs

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get the records in last exact 24 hrs?

```
Select * from TABLE1 where SENTDATE >= SYSDATE - 1
```

When I ran the above query at 00:05 hrs, it is returning the records in only last five minutes. I need to fetch the records in last exact 24 hrs from when the query is run.

How this can be achieved in SQL/Oracle
Is there any way which will be similar to

```
Select * from TABLE1 where SENTDATE >= sysdate - 24 hrs ?
```

Comment: `SYSDATE - 1` *is* "sysdate - 24 hrs". Maybe your `SENTDATE` doesn't have the time portion (i.e. set to 0:00 for all records)? - in which case you need to truncate sysdate as well - e.g. `TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1` as per David's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Running it at 5 minutes past suggests that you're looking for "yesterday", which would be:

```
sentdate >= trunc(sysdate)-1 and
sentdate <  trunc(sysdate)
```

If you do want the exact last 24 hours then:

```
sentdate >= sysdate-1 and
sentdate <  sysdate
```

or:

```
sentdate >  sysdate-1 and
sentdate <= sysdate
```

Be very careful of boundary conditions, hence using >= and <, or > and <= in the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE sentdate BETWEEN SYSDATE - 1 AND SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally sysdate - 1 will give date with timestamp as well but if you are facing problem then you can apply condition as below -

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1
 WHERE Sentdate >= To_Date(To_Char((SYSDATE - 1), 'YYYYMMDD') || ' ' ||
                           To_Char(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
                           'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a function like DateDIFF() :

```
    Select * from TABLE1 where DateDIFF(MINUTES, SENTDATE, SYSDATE) < 1440
```